# Clonezilla clone to qemu/kvm virtual machine

Tags: boot, virtual-machine, qemu, clonezilla

i created a virtual machine on qemu and started it from clonezilla iso. After that i plugged hard drive and installed my prepared os to virtual machine. After restart i am getting:

> Booting from Hard Disk...

Screenshot:
[image]

I used i686 iso. Any idea what to do at this point?

Comment: Using CloneZilla with a VM is mostly redundant by the way, you can use the virtual hard drive image directly for most purposes. // Please describe in greater detail what you did with the VM, I'm struggling to follow.

Comment: @DanielB I have a harddrive that consists a linux clone. I want to extract that clone to a vm. I can install it directly to my pc with using clonezilla boot usb and my harddrive without any problem. But now i want to install it to a vm if it is possible. I followed up the same procedure but got that error you see.